# When I use setState callback to toggleDropdown my dropdown is open after selecting item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have dropdown and toggleDropdown fucntion which change state by setState callback:

```
  toggleDropdown =() => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ opened: !prevState.opened }));
  }
```

Problem is cus when I select item in dropdown, dropdown should be closed, but it's not when I use setState callback. 
Actually it's closed on 1 second and then is open again.

But If I use current state to change the state it's works fine.

```
  toggleDropdown =() => {
    this.setState({ opened: !this.state.opened });
  }
```

Why That's happening?

Here is the main part of dropdown component:

```
class SimpleDropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: props.selectValue,
      opened: false
    };

  }

  toggleDropdown =() => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ opened: !prevState.opened }));
  }

  onSelect = (option) => {
    this.setState({ selected: option, opened: false });
    this.props.onSelect(option);
  };

  handleClickOutside = () => {
    this.setState({ opened: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    const { title, isLoading } = this.props;
    console.warn('this.state.opened', this.state.opened);

    return (
      <div className="simple-dropdown" onClick={this.toggleDropdown} role="button">
        <span className="dropdown-title">{title}:</span>
        <span>{selected.value}</span>
```

Comment: try using spread operator in order not to mutate the object

Comment: {...prevState, opened: !prevState.opened }

Comment: could be that your handleClickOutside is invoked before toggleDropdown? cant see from the code how is the handleClickOutside used?

Comment: @jure it's used as wrapper for component: export default onClickOutside(SimpleDropdown); 
it's called every time when click outside of component body.

Comment: @MarkJames maybe try to console.log inside handleClickOutside.. might be that the click outside is invoked before onClick.. guessing here :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the spread operator to not mutate the object, 
change

```
{ opened: !prevState.opened }
```

to

```
{...prevState, opened: !prevState.opened }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but still does not work... Cannot understand...